# Why does CNN only predict one class

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I have a model that needs to detect if a plant is dead or alive. It is only predicting one class, that data is imbalanced, but i have used weights to counter the imbalance.

I have looked at loads of questions about this problem, but none seem to work, apparently this problem occurs when overfitting, so I have used dropout. But the model still only predicts one class.

Heres the model:

```
model=Sequential()

# Convolutional layer / input layer
model.add(Conv2D(60, 5,5, activation='relu', input_shape=np.shape(X[1])))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3)))

model.add(Dropout(0.8))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dropout(0.7))

model.add(Dense(130, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dropout(0.6))

# Output layer
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))


model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
optimizer='adam',
metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, y, epochs=6, batch_size=32, class_weight=class_weight, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

Usually it should predict both classes with 1: a healthy plant and 0: 
 an unhealthy plant

Comment: what is the shape of your labels? one-hot? it is not the problem, but I need to know to shape the answer.

Comment: what do you mean by the shape of the labels, i am sorry i don't understand as i am a beginner in neural networks

Comment: `print(y.shape)` - what does it print?

Comment: sorry my bad, it is (20640, 2)

Comment: If my answer won't work the problem is in what you're passing in `class_weight`.

Answer (score 0):

Since your problem is a binary classification and your output dimensionality is 2, you should change your activation to softmax.

```
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
```

However, if you want to keep sigmoid just change your output layer units to 1, this way you will output how likely your input is one of the two classes with only one unit.

```
 model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Comment: I have tried this and is is still predicting one class

Comment: What class is unbalanced? And could you show your class_weight?

Comment: the healthy class is unbalanced, the class weights is  class_weights={healthy:0.8, unhealthy:0.2}

Comment: I'm guessing you hardcoded these values, so instead compute them with sklearn or try applying them like one of these answers: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/how-to-set-class-weights-for-imbalanced-classes-in-keras